# Issue on httpost, send multiple variables

Tags: android

i have this code here, now, i'm just able to send the value parameter, i can't send the others.

What should i do in order to send the other values of the editText type?
I.e i want to be able to send : mbiemer with httpost method...but how..

Thanks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mbiemer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgMbiemer);
    telefon=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgTelefon);
    adresa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgAdresa);
    ora=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgOra);
    per=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgPer);
    dyqan=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgDyqan);
    statusi=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgStatusi);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(value.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());  
    }
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.28/app/app1.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send **mbiemer**  because you are not sending it

change your code to this

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.28/app/app1.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", value.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mbiemer", mbiemer.getText().toString()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

and call postData(); in your doInBackground

Comment: this was so perfect :)
thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What should i do in order to send the other values of the editText
>   type?

you can use any data structure like `ArrayList` for accessing values in `doInBackground`. second option is you can pass all parameters in an sequence in `AsyncTask.execute()` using [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) as:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString(),
             mbiemer.getText().toString(),
             telefon.getText().toString(),...);
```

and now  retrieve all values in `doInBackground` using index as:

```
@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String str_value=params[0];
String str_mbiemer=params[1];
String str_telefon=params[2];
.....
postData(params[0]);
return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
so, up to here it's fine, i understand it.. but how can i post it here:         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Comment: should i do postData(params[0]); postData(params[1]);postData(params[2]); etc etc?

Comment: @alandr : u want to send all these values with url? then pass theses values in postData as `postData(params[0],params[1],params[2],..)` and inside `postData` method add theses values in  `nameValuePairs` as : `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param0", params[0]));nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", params[1]));,....`

Comment: you are still not sending mbiemer. As you actually sending the data in postData() method. It will be pointless to pass all the arguments in doInBackground but not postData();